# Probability of $B\cap A^\complement$ given $P(A)$, $P(B)$, $P(A\cap B)$.

Tags: probability

> A total of 28 percent of American males smoke cigarettes, 7% smoke cigars, 5% smoke cigars and cigarettes. How many smoke cigars but not cigarettes?

Let's assume that:

$P(A)$ = people smoking cigarettes

$P(B)$ = people smoking cigars

According to my class notes the solution to the above problem is this:

$ P(B ∩ A^\complement) = P(B) - P(B ∩ A)$

Even thought I understand theoretically why this is done I would also like to be able to prove this mathematically based on the axioms of the Kolmogorov probability and it's properties.

Could anyone explain the steps that lead to the result in more detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the finite additivity property of the probability measure:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(B) & = \mathbb{P}(B\cap\Omega)\\\\
& = \mathbb{P}(B\cap(A\cup A^{c}))\\\\
& = \mathbb{P}((B\cap A)\cup(B\cap A^{c}))\\\\
& = \mathbb{P}(B\cap A) + \mathbb{P}(B\cap A^{c})
\end{align*}

The last relation holds because $(B\cap A)\cap(B\cap A^{c}) = \varnothing$.

Comment: That's quite exhaustive, thank you so much! Now it makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @ΝεφέληΚάσα You are welcome ! I am glad I could help.